# Force html form to submit plain text only

Tags: html, forms, plaintext

I have an html form that I want to force to convert whatever content it receives to plain text before sending it to my server (kind of similar to what happens in a simple text editor like OS-X TextEdit: where we can convert to PlainText whatever RichText formatted content). How do I do that? I don't really care where the user sees in the TextAreas, etc. I specifically want the text that arrives on the server to have been converted to PlainText.

Comment: striptag function may help you....!

Comment: I don't know much html. where would I put the striptag function?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `Jsoup`.

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Comment: Using this approach removes all line breaks. I still want the line breaks to be intact. I just want to leave it plain text.